# Magento - Random text on 'Shopping cart' page

Tags: checkout, template, currency

Im having a magento online shop in Australia. Im try to add a text line right before the "proceed to checkout" button. I have tried to look for the phtml that controls this page, but couldn't find one.

The main reason that im doing that is becouse i want to let customer know that they are paying with AU$ and not US$.
Anyone idea how to do this? or even a better way for solving that?

will be much appritiated!

[image: random text]

Comment: which magento version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goto `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/YourTemplate/templat/Checkout/Onepage/link.phtml`

There you can the code .it will resolved your issue

Comment: I just want to add that you can turn on template Hints in the Admin -> Advanced -> Developer so you can see which block is dumping the random text.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the currency symbols in the system menu, so another option is to change "$" to "AU$" there.